# Where to keep dependencies (large files or directory structures) for use with Docker/Docker-Compose?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

As part of my Docker setup for a development environment, I'm managing the following using Docker-Compose:

- A MySQL instance (called `database` in the `docker-compose.yaml` file) based off `mysql:5.7`
- Two Tomcat instances (called `manager` and `runtime`) based off `tomcat:7.0`. These two depend on the database to be present, which works fine through a `link` provided by docker-compose.

As part of the container build, I map several SQL scripts into the database container, these are loaded into the database upon creation.

For the Tomcat instances, I need to deploy a separate WAR file into each of the containers: `manager.war` into `manager` and `runtime.war` into `runtime`. Each of these WAR files is about 120 MB in size.

To keep things simple, I have added the WAR files to the Git project that I use for managing the `docker-compose` project. In addition to the `docker-compose.yaml` file and the WAR files, the project contains SQL data and some shell scripts that I map into the respective containers.

My biggest question at the moment is where to keep the WAR files, as they increase the size of the Git repo dramatically. Since I expect updates to the WAR files over time (they are created/versionized outside of this project), I will have to replace these files from time to time with updated copies, further increasing the size of the repo, which will make it difficult for people to just clone the repo.

How to address something like this? I know it's generally a bad practice to keep binary files like these in a Git repo, but I also want to keep the files close to the project, so people using this don't have to start searching/downloading the files before being able to use this.

Is there a feature in Docker or Docker-Compose that would help me with managing these "dependencies"?

Answer (score 1):

> My biggest question at the moment is where to keep the WAR files, as they increase the size of the Git repo dramatically

---

Use [this tool](https://git-lfs.github.com/):

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good solution for this problem. I'll explore whether I can use this for my purpose. Thanks!